# Deploy context.xml file using maven plugin

Tags: java, xml, maven, tomcat, context.xml

I am trying to deploy a webapp to a Tomcat (on a remote system) using the maven plugin

```
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
```

I need to deploy the same war file with different context.xml files from my machine (M1) to the machine running the tomcat (M2). From what I understand here https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat6-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html this should be possible using the options

```
<mode>both</mode>
<contextFile>PATH_TO_CONTEXT.XML</contextFile>
```

(where I configure PATH_TO_CONTEXT.XML using profiles) and the command

```
mvn tomcat6:deploy -P MY_PROFILE.
```

The problem is that for each setting of PATH_TO_CONTEXT.XML the deployment fails.

A) Specifying PATH_TO_CONTEXT.XML to point to a file on the machine M1 (where I run the maven command), I get BUILD SUCCESS from Maven, however nothing is deployed. According to the tomcat log the reason is that the file is not available on the machine running the tomcat:

```
[ INFO] [catalina-exec-32] [] [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager]] - Manager: install: Installing context configuration at 'file:PATH_TO_CONTEXT.XML' from 'file:PATH_TO_WAR'
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/05/15 22:41:39 | java.io.FileNotFoundException: PATH_TO_CONTEXT.XML (No such file or directory)
```

where PATH_TO_WAR points to the war on M1.

B) Specifying a PATH_TO_CONTEXT.XML pointing to a file on M2 (the tomcat's machine) the maven process finishes with BUILD FAILURE due to

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat6-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project PROJECT: Cannot find context file: PATH_TO_CONTEXT -> [Help 1]
```

Thus the only situation where this config works is when I run the deploy command on the machine that also runs the tomcat (M1=M2). Is there a valid config for a deployment from one machine to another?

Answer (score 0):

The deploy plugin expects the `<contextFile>` to refer to a file *already* on the target machine.

It's still marked as "beta", but he [wagon](http://mojo.codehaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/) plugin looks like a possibility for installing the context file on the target system.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, this ist exactly the problem with my alternative B). There I already have the file on the target machine, but maven claims that it cannot be found.